# Can I protect native JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, security, native

Is there any way to prevent a user from overriding a native function?

Example:

```
var getRand;
(function(){
  'use strict';
  getRand = function(){
    return Math.random();
  }
})();

getRand(); //gives a nice random number
```

After the page has loaded, overriding in console.

```
Math.random = function (){ return 0 };

getRand(); //gives 0 :(
```

Is there any way to prevent native functions from being overridden? Maybe with CSP or sealing the Object... is this even possible?

Comment: Why are you even trying to do this? You give the user the JS and they are free to do with it as they will - including ignoring it totally. All JS is there is to make the page more interactive (here I am assuming that this is not node.js as this is implied by the question)

Comment: Lets say your sending this random number via ajax and want to make sure it's random.

Comment: You cannot be sure of anything that is sent via AJAX. Communication can be modified en-route.

Comment: Lets say you're using a firebase promise to retrieve a variable and the data is in a reference which needs access a global. 

return $fireObject(myObj.$ref().$loaded().then(function(data){
  return data * Math.random();
});

The question isn't about the why, just if the concept is possible

Comment: Just do not use JS for security. The browser/hacker can thwart you as they see fit.

Comment: Thanks for the warning

Comment: "The question isn't about the why, just if the concept is possible" There would be less useless questions if the questions were about the why rather than how ;)

Comment: What is the threat this is supposed to be defending against? If “a user” is the owner of the computer, they can change their browser (eg with extensions) to sabotage anything about the JavaScript execution environment before any document code runs. And if you are trying to run untrusted code in the same origin, it can simply pop open a new document with a new scripting context, grab content from the Same Origin and alter/execute it in any way it likes. So it's difficult to see what practical purpose could be served by this.

Comment: The purpose was to protect native functions, so a library couldn't override an existing function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, you can use [`Object.freeze(Math)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze):

> The Object.freeze() method freezes an object: that is, prevents new
>   properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from
>   being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their
>   enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed. In
>   essence the object is made effectively immutable. The method returns
>   the object being frozen.

```
Object.freeze(Math);

// This won't work or it won't replace
// the function with the whole string...
Math.random = "hello world";
```

Unless any other library could be relying on extending or modifying `Math` (for example, maybe a *polyfill* might need to add a function or whatever to `Math` but as I said before, it's just a possible issue when freezing a built-in object...).

### You can also *freeze* individual properties...

...using `Object.defineProperty(...)` to modify an existing property descriptor:

```
Object.defineProperty(Math, "random", { 
    configurable: false,
    writable: false 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Comment: @rid `freeze` is not part of  `Object.prototype` btw. It's a direct member of `Object`.

Comment: @ilovetoast I've updated my answer to provide you another approach. Well, actually `Object.freeze` is equivalent to setting all property descriptors to `{ writable: false, configurable: false }`...