# JavaScript: is it permitted to override a standard built-in object?

Tags: javascript

For example, I want to replace the standard `Date` or `Math` objects with my own.

I know it is unwise and will cause subtle problems like ones with `instanceof` or `toString.call`, let's assume that all known public behavior of the replacee is imitated. Does the standard permit such an action?

Comment: `Does standart permit such action?` Yes.

Comment: Not recommended but possible.

Comment: To those voting to close as "primarily opinion based", it's a question that has a definitive answer, so why are you voting to close it as POB?

Comment: Yes it is permitted, but you might want to elaborate on the need to do so because there might be a better approach to it that you are not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the standard permit such an action?

Yes. You can override methods for native objects like console, Date etc, though not [unpreventable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532808/can-i-protect-native-javascript-functions) for who don't have a *prototype* like `Math`.

For example,

```
Date.prototype.getDate = function(){ return 5 }; //overriding getDate method

new Date().getDate() //returns 5
```

Comment: i understand that i can modify native objects, but can i do this: `window.Date = MyDate`

Comment: Anything in the global scope can be modified.